# Stored procedure successfully created, but doesn't do anything

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, while-loop, sql-update, sql-insert

The stored procedure is created, but when I try to call it, it doesn't insert and/or update anything.

This is my code:

```
use KlantArtikelMathijs
GO

alter procedure SPVerhoogPrijzen 
    @catcode varchar(32),
    @ingangsdatum date
as
begin 
    declare @artikelnr int;
    declare @prijs decimal(8,2);

    if(@ingangsdatum < GETDATE())
        raiserror('deze datum is in het verleden, kies een andere datum', 16,1)
        return

    if(@catcode not in (select catcode from artikel))
        raiserror('Deze categorie bestaat niet, maak eerst een artikel met deze categorie aan', 16 , 1)
        return

    declare @counter int = 0

    while @counter < (select count(artikelnr) from artikel where catcode = @catcode)
    begin
        set @artikelnr = (select artikelnr from artikel where catcode = @catcode)
        set @prijs = (select sum(prijs*1.1) from artikelprijs where artikelnr = @artikelnr)

        update artikelprijs
        set einddatum = dateadd(day,-1,@ingangsdatum)
        where artikelnr = @artikelnr

        insert into artikelprijs (artikelnr, prijs, begindatum, einddatum)
        values (@artikelnr, @prijs, @ingangsdatum, '2099-12-31')

        set @counter = @counter + 1

        if @counter = 3
        begin
            break
        end
    end
end
```

First I'm checking if the "ingangsdatum" (date) is greater than the date which is already in the database (this is necessary). After that I check if the Category code is in the database (this is necessary too).

Then I update one table and insert in another.

I'm using a loop because the select statement returns more than 1 record.

[This is my database I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2fsd.jpg)

Comment: Which dbms? (sql server?)

Comment: yes, microsoft Sql management studio

Comment: Does it show any error message?

Comment: no it does not ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to execute **more than one statement** after an `IF`, you **must use** a `begin ... end` block.....

You have this:

```
if(@ingangsdatum < GETDATE())
    raiserror('deze datum is in het verleden, kies een andere datum', 16,1)
    return
```

But this - properly indented and written - is really:

```
if(@ingangsdatum < GETDATE())
    raiserror('deze datum is in het verleden, kies een andere datum', 16,1)

return
```

The `return` **does NOT** belong to the `IF` clause code - it is executed **every time** you reach this point! So when the `IF` condition is *not matched* - you just unconditionally return from the procedure, and the rest of the code is **never** executed......

You need to write it like this:

```
if(@ingangsdatum < GETDATE())
begin     -- add the "begin" to start the block of code
    raiserror('deze datum is in het verleden, kies een andere datum', 16,1)
    return
end       -- add the "end" to close the block of code
```

Comment: @MFox: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm pretty new to stackoverflow